# mixing decrator pattern and factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

We currently use User Interface Process from Microsoft.
Which basically tends to be an MVP "Framework".
Controllers communicate with each other over Input/Output-Arguments.

A controller defines these two methods `void OnEnterTask(object inputArguments)`, `OutputArguments OnLeaveTask()`.
Basically all inputarguments contain xml-data.

the inputarguments are just dto's, so its up to the controller how to interpret the xml.

the scenario:

`CalculateProductInputArgs` -> `ProductController` -> `CalculateProductOutputArgs`

if the productcontroller just needs to handle single products that work very well.
but it needs to be able to communicate with a CompositeProductController.
Which sends `CalculateCompositeProductInput/OutputArgs`

so my thougts are a combination of decorators which is created by a factory

code (pseudo python):

```
class Processor:
    """abstract"""
    def ProcessInput(input):
        pass

    def ProcessOutput(output):
        pass

class ProductProcessor(Processor):
    """implements specific product behaviour"""
    pass

class CompositeProductProcessor(ProductProcessor):
    """implements specific product behaviour"""
    def __init__(productprocessor):
        self.processor = productprocessor

    def ProcessInput(input)
        productInput = input.Product
        compositeData = input.CompositeData
        self.processor(productInput)    

class Factory:
    def CreateProcessor(input):
        productprocessor = ProductProcessor() #maybe a specialized processor
        if input.IsComposite():
            composite = CompositeProductProcessor(productprocessor)
            return composite
        return productprocessor
```

my simple question.
is it a good practice? or do you have better ideas?

greetings :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite reasonable to have a factory that decides what decorator(s) you need to create.

The only change I can suggest is that you find a different name for `CompositeProductProcessor` as it's not an implementation of the Composite pattern, and the naming might be confusing to the reader.